# Move a LetsEncrypt certificate from one machine to another

Tags: unix, letsencrypt

I've used a LetsEncrypt certificate for my personal web server for some time, updated it a few times and it works fine. Now I'm migrating to a new machine (with a slightly different flavour of unix).

How do I transfer my certificate to the new machine, and how do I make the LetsEncrypt client work on that new machine?

Silly me thought it would be as simple as transferring the `/etc/letsencrypt` directory, but it seems I was mistaken.

After doing that, running `letsencrypt-renewer` throws a very strange exception that ends up in

```
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char *' must be a str or list or tuple, not unicode
```

from `OpenSSL/crypto.py`.

Under `/etc/letsencrypt/accounts/` there are directories with names that looks like hashes, and thereunder is a meta.json file that contains the *internal* name of the machine I used to create the certificate.

Running `letsencrypt certonly` gives me the opportunity to select an account(!) where I can choose from the *old* machine's internal name and the *new* machines internal name.

Chosing either, and submitting the name of my domain, yields the same error (edited for ... anonymity)

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

Domain: <mydomain>
Type:   urn:acme:error:unauthorized
Detail: Incorrect validation certificate for TLS-SNI-01 challenge.
Requested <hexadeciman29positions>.<morehexadecimal>
<hexadecimal>.acme.invalid from <myip>:443. Received certificate
containing '<mydomain>'
```

So... I guess there are some key files that I have neglected. Or something else I don't understand.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

So this comes a bit late and it might not be relevant to the OP anymore, but for anyone who comes across the same problem, the following worked for me:

```
letsencrypt --renew-with-new-domains
```

I had the same issue of wanting to transfer a cert from one server to another (and with a different Linux distro). I just `rsync`'d the `/etc/letsencrypt/` directory to the new server, ran the above command and followed the dialogue thereafter.